# Fail2Ban not picking up dropbear auth failures

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, fail2ban, dropbear

raspbian
Linux [hostname] 4.9.36+ #1015 Thu Jul 6 16:07:57 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux

fail2ban is not picking up the dropbear auth failures.  This was working for openssh without issues.  I went to dropbear to reduce memory usage.

Here is my auth.log to show logging is working

```
dropbear[2640]: Bad password attempt for 'username' from 192.168.1.151:50780
```

My jail.local

```
#dropbear shh config password

[dropbear]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = dropbear
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
bantime = 900
banaction = iptables-allports
findtime = 900
maxretry = 3
```

My dropbear.conf fail2ban filter

```
[Definition]

_daemon = dropbear

# Option:  failregex
# Notes.:  regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile. The
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>" can
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)
# Values:  TEXT

# These match the unmodified dropbear messages. It isn't possible to
# match the source of the 'exit before auth' messages from dropbear.
#
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)slogin attempt for nonexistent user ('.*' )?from <HOST>:.*\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sbad password attempt for .+ from <HOST>:.*\s*$

# The only line we need to match with the modified dropbear.

# NOTE: The failregex below is ONLY intended to work with a patched
# version of Dropbear as described here:
# http://www.unchartedbackwaters.co.uk/pyblosxom/static/patches
```

And the standard jail.config (these options should be overwrote with the .local jail)

```
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.
#
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/dropbear
maxretry = 6
```

Comment: Yea that was exactly it. The default regular expression in the fail2ban dropbear filter has a typo...or the log string for dropbear has a typo depending on how you want to look at !  Please put an answer so I can vote you up man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dropbear.conf` regex does not match the entries in `auth.log`:

```
Bad password attempt for...  /* auth.log */
bad password attempt for...  /* dropbear.conf */
```

If you edit `dropbear.conf` to respect case, fail2ban should catch the logged authentication failures.

Comment: ^%(__prefix_line)slogin attempt for nonexistent user ('.*' )?from <HOST>:.*\s*$  also needs to be changed for this condition to work!