# Fail2Ban not picking up dropbear auth failures - again

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, fail2ban

RASPBIAN Jessie

**Edit: It is working from some clients**

From another Rasberry Pi the log is working and now picking up the proper entry in the log

```
Jul 22 04:02:21 <HOSTNAME> dropbear[2462]: Bad password attempt for
'user' from 192.168.1.154:39594
```

But when I try from my mac i get this

```
Jul 22 04:29:27 <HOSTNAME> dropbear[3026]: Bad password attempt for 'user' from fe80::109b:c195:be5d:6e5e%eth0:63395
```

It is trying to use a IPV6 address...for some reason.

I had a similar thread that can be found here [Fail2Ban not picking up dropbear auth failures](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378026/fail2ban-not-picking-up-dropbear-auth-failures)

I did get this working but had to restore from a backup(unrelated), however, that backup did not include my fix for this. Following restoration, I had re-install drop bear and re-configure fail2ban, however, it would appear the regular expressions have changed once again.  Last time it was a capital vs lower case B that was the culprit but not this time, as you can see below that appear to have been addressed in the version of fail2ban I am running now.  But it is still not picking up the auto failures.

**Auth log error**

```
dropbear[740]: Bad password attempt for 'username' from 192.168.1.171:62556
```

**Current filter**

```
# Fail2Ban filter for dropbear
#
# NOTE: The regex below is ONLY intended to work with a patched
# version of Dropbear as described here:
# http://www.unchartedbackwaters.co.uk/pyblosxom/static/patches
#            ^%(__prefix_line)sexit before auth from <HOST>.*\s*$
#
# The standard Dropbear output doesn't provide enough information to
# ban all types of attack.  The Dropbear patch adds IP address
# information to the 'exit before auth' message which is always
# produced for any form of non-successful login. It is that message
# which this file matches.
#
# More information: http://bugs.debian.org/546913

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = dropbear

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s[Ll]ogin attempt for nonexistent user ('.*' )?from <HOST>:\d+$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s[Bb]ad (PAM )?password attempt for .+ from <HOST>(:\d+)?$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s[Ee]xit before auth \(user '.+', \d+ fails\): Max auth tries reached - user '.+' from <HOST>:\d+\s*$

ignoreregex =

# DEV Notes:
#
# The first two regexs here match the unmodified dropbear messages. It isn't
# possible to match the source of the 'exit before auth' messages from dropbear
# as they don't include the "from <HOST>" bit.
#
# The second last failregex line we need to match with the modified dropbear.
#
# For the second regex the following apply:
#
# http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/external/dropbear/svr-authpam.c
# http://svn.dd-wrt.com/changeset/16642#file64
```

**Fail2ban jail.conf**

```
# [SECTION_NAME]
# enabled = true

#
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.
#
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

[dropbear]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6

# Generic filter for pam. Has to be used with action which bans all ports
# such as iptables-allports, shorewall
[pam-generic]
```

**Fail2Ban jail.local**

```
#local ssh rule set

[ssh]

enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
bantime = 900
banaction = iptables-allports
findtime = 900
maxretry = 3

#dropbear ssh config

[dropbear]

enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = dropbear
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
bantime = 900
banaction = iptables-allports
findtime = 900
maxretry = 3
```

**IPTABLEs -L output**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-dropbear  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-dropbear (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**When I run the regex**

```
fail2ban-regex "Nov 15 09:09:16 gw dropbear[16806]: Bad password attempt for 'root' from 104.223.180.34:3703" config/filter.d/dropbear.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : config/filter.d/dropbear.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fail2ban-regex", line 430, in <module>
    fail2banRegex.readRegex(cmd_regex, 'fail') or sys.exit(-1)
  File "/usr/bin/fail2ban-regex", line 227, in readRegex
    'add%sRegex' % regextype.title())(regex.getFailRegex())
  File "/usr/share/fail2ban/server/filter.py", line 95, in addFailRegex
    raise e
server.failregex.RegexException: No 'host' group in 'config/filter.d/dropbear.conf'
```

Comment: I found this note https://www.unchartedbackwaters.co.uk/pyblosxom/static/patches and copied the contents of the suggested filter into my dropbear filter (same as old working) but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Alright to stop the Mac from using IPV6 i have to disable it at the command line.  Despite showing as being "unconfigured" in the GUI is was still getting and IPV6 address from my DHCP server. Here are the steps i took.

1) Disable IPV6 on mac

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi $$ networksetup -setv6off Ethernet (-usesetv6automatic to enable)
```

2) Made sure my DHCP server (in this case its the box I was installing fail2ban and dropbear on) isnt service IPV6

3) If you need to Disable IPV6 on the lixun machine (either target or host)

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1 
=0 will enable
```

4) I ended up back at the default fail2ban drop bear filter. It seems its been updated since my last post to capture the potential error message case difference.

```
# Fail2Ban filter for dropbear
#
# NOTE: The regex below is ONLY intended to work with a patched
# version of Dropbear as described here:
# http://www.unchartedbackwaters.co.uk/pyblosxom/static/patches
#            ^%(__prefix_line)sexit before auth from <HOST>.*\s*$
#
# The standard Dropbear output doesn't provide enough information to
# ban all types of attack.  The Dropbear patch adds IP address
# information to the 'exit before auth' message which is always
# produced for any form of non-successful login. It is that message
# which this file matches.
#
# More information: http://bugs.debian.org/546913

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]

_daemon = dropbear

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s[Ll]ogin attempt for nonexistent user ('.*' )?from <HOST>:\d+$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s[Bb]ad (PAM )?password attempt for .+ from <HOST>(:\d+)?$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s[Ee]xit before auth \(user '.+', \d+ fails\): Max auth tries reached - user '.+' from <HOST>:\d+\s*$

ignoreregex =

# DEV Notes:
#
# The first two regexs here match the unmodified dropbear messages. It isn't
# possible to match the source of the 'exit before auth' messages from dropbear
# as they don't include the "from <HOST>" bit.
#
# The second last failregex line we need to match with the modified dropbear.
#
# For the second regex the following apply:
#
# http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/external/dropbear/svr-authpam.c
# http://svn.dd-wrt.com/changeset/16642#file64
```

5) Make sure IP-tables is working at expected using the tables -L command should show similar output to mine (assuming you have no other rules).  I had to update my kernal using rpi-update.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-dropbear  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-dropbear (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```